# MySQL - Select group by with minimum value

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with the following data:

```
id | descr | val1 | val2
========================
1  | 'aa'  |  1   |  5
2  | 'bb'  |  2   |  7
3  | 'bb'  |  3   |  1
4  | 'bb'  |  4   |  19
5  | 'aa'  |  5   |  1
6  | 'aa'  |  6   |  8
7  | 'bb'  |  7   |  11
8  | 'bb'  |  8   |  3
9  | 'aa'  |  9   |  16
10 | 'aa'  |  10  |  9
```

I want to select the rows for each unique `descr` with the minimum value of `val2`.
Expected result:

```
id | descr | val1 | val2
========================
3  | 'bb'  |  3   |  1
5  | 'aa'  |  5   |  1
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT *, min(val2) minVal FROM test group by descr
```

By the result had no relation to the data in the row of the minimum value:

```
id | descr | val1 | val2 | minVal
==================================
1  | 'aa'  |  1   |  5   |  1
2  | 'bb'  |  2   |  7   |  1
```

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: Incidentally, this is the most frequently asked question under the MySQL tag on SO. Occasionally, as below, it's correctly answered too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One standard way of dealing with this in MySQL, which doesn't have wide support for analytic functions, is to use a subquery which identifies the minimum `val2` values for each `descr` group.  Then use this subquery to restrict the records of `test` to what you want appearing in your result set.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT descr, MIN(val2) AS min_val2
    FROM test
    GROUP BY descr
) t2
    ON t1.descr = t2.descr AND
       t1.val2  = t2.min_val2
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle